# The Terraria endgame, what is left to do?

Tags: terraria

I wear a full set of molten armor.
I use Muramasa, Blue Moon and a Pheonix Blaster as weapons.
 
I defeated the Eye of Cthulhu, the Eater of World and Skeletron.
I killed a goblin army without ever being in any real danger.
I explored the Dungeon, the Underground Jungle and the Underworld.

What is there left to do?

- What is there left to kill that might still provide a challenge?
- What places are there left to explore that still contain some secrets?
- What ludicrous buildings or contraptions are still to be to build?

Comment: [My name is Ozymandias, king of kings!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ozymandias) :p

Comment: Have you found any floating islands yet? Exploring for them (without using a map of your world) might provide an additional challenge, and some additional treasure.

Comment: Farm Bone Serpents / Imps / Demons for some rare items: Sunfury, Flamelash, Demon Scythe, and Guide Voodoo doll.

Comment: I think at this point you should consider creating something amazing within the world.  Maybe raining lava from the sky or a true floating castle!  Use your imagination and building something incredible!

Comment: I haven't really played Terraria yet, but this seems kinda like it needs a spoiler tag, no?

Comment: @chands There is no spoiler tag on Earth or under it yet created by programming's greatest minds that can prevent someone from willfully clicking on a title that plainly says "Terraria endgame".

Comment: I don't think this question is entirely answerable. By design, Terraria is an open-ended game. If you're satisfied with your equipment, and done exploring, that's it. In short - you can do any number of things, so is a single comprehensive answer even an option?

Comment: Did the wall of flesh have yet to exist back when this question was asked? Please see @japnoo's answer below. Also, a new update came out just days ago and I've seen rope, paint, higher-capacity chests, and some fun look-and-feel improvements.

Comment: Moon Lord:  *laughs mockingly*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Terraria does not have an end. It's a sandbox. Feel free to do whatever you want! You are using a Muramasa, but it's not the strongest weapon, it's actually one of four items needed to craft the strongest one! [(Night's Edge)](http://wiki.terrariaonline.com/Night%27s_Edge)

**Go build something great!** There are many forums where you can find people building really amazing things in Terraria, like castles, big forts, houses, etc.

**Pixel art!** Yes, Terraria is just block, blocks and blocks. Various colours, textures - this can serve as a great set of "painting" tools. And what's the canvas? The world!

**PvP.** Like it was mentioned in other answers, you can fight other players.

**Download custom maps** - there are tons of custom maps already, with maze games, adventures, role plays.. Just [pick one.](http://terraria.curseforge.com/maps/)

Last but not least - **wait for the 1.1 update!** It's gonna be huge ;)

The release of 1.1 is planned for the first of December, and there are going to be [really interesting things!](http://www.terrariaonline.com/threads/bunny-power.61945/)

Comment: Thanks for the curse map link! A great resource with some very interesting maps.

Answer (score 6):

PvP!

Start a multiplayer server, get one or three friends together, organise yourselves into two teams, and then have a race to do something, or just try and kill each other.

Answer (score 3):

You've conquered the world, now go destroy it.  One of the ideas I've been toying with is the complete destruction of a world, without hacked items.  Dynamite/dig everything out, fill in water and lava, keep some lava to destroy more.  Purify the world as the dryad requests, but on a scale that she just never contemplated.  All that should be left is a few demon altars, unless you lucked out and have a world where they are all on sand.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but go down to your mine and go to hell. Try to find and kill a voodoo demon, get the guide voodoo doll it drops, and after that go near lava and throw the voodoo doll in the lava. The wall of flesh will spawn, kill it and then you will be in hardmode. A lot of new things will be available. You have just started the game my friend. If you need any help on hardmode look it up on Google.

Answer (score 0):

Have you got *every* item? If not why not! [There's a list here](http://wiki.TerrariaOnline.com)

Answer (score 0):

Well, beat the hardmode bosses (that means kill the wall of flesh), get the best armor (that is DEFINITELY NOT MOLTEN) and weapons, and build yourself a castle to live in. Build a system for a (almost) wireless Blood Moon/goblin invasion lockdown system for your NPC's.

Comment: You do realize that Molten was most likely the best armor when the question was asked... approximately one year ago?

Answer (score 0):

You could always start a brand new world, and explore methods you haven't before.  You can even take your old character, with full gear, and see how quickly you can conquer this new world, beat all the bosses, get all the NPCs, and get all the way through Hardmode.

Oh, and there's hardmode now too.  Not to mention new 1.2 stuff. So have fun with that.  ;)